# geting the absolute position of an element in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a series of elements setup like the example below:

`<div id="floater"></div>`

`<div id="alert"></div>`
`<div id="news"></div>`
`<div id="links"></div>`

When a link in the `links div` is clicked I used jQuery to animate the `floater` div to its position so as the user can easily reference the last link they clicked.

However. `alert` is setup to fade out and vanish `onClick` and `news` is setup with a toggle so that it accordions in and out of view.

Depending on the state of `alert` and `news` the `floater` will animate to an incorrect position.

Is there a way to get the actual true current position of an element in jQuery other than `offset()` or `position()`?

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the native offset values:

//pure js

```
element.offsetLeft
element.offsetTop
element.offsetWidth
element.offsetWidth
```

//jquery

```
$(element).attr('offsetLeft');
$(element)[0].offsetLeft;
$(element).get(0).offsetLeft;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [pageX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.pageX)/[pageY](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.pageY) attributes of the element.

Comment: Those are an event object attributes. Not the attributes of a DOM element.